# Dynamic printing array

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic, printing

I have a workbook with 50+ worksheets each being a different business division. I want to set up numerous macros to print combinations of these sheets based on the defined group that they are in (e.g. one printout would be sheets 4, 12, 20 another sheets 2, 5, 10 etc). These combinations will vary (i.e. be dynamic) over time (e.g. sheets will be added to print groups, sheets will be reallocated between print groups etc.

On a separate sheet, I was wanting to set up the print groups in columns e.g. B2:B5 would print group 1 (Sheet4, Sheet12, Sheet20). C2:C[X] print group 2 etc

Within VBA, how do I reference these columns for the purposes of selecting the array? Thanks Ben

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an Enumeration coupled with a custom function to return an array of worksheets to process.  Sheets can process an array of sheet names or indices.  he advantage of using an Enumeration is that enumerated values are available to intellisense.

[image]

```
Enum PrintDivisions
    EastSide
    WestSide
    Central
    NorthAmerica
End Enum


Function getPrintDivision(Division As PrintDivisions)
    Select Case Division
    Case PrintDivisions.Central
        getPrintDivision = Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet3.Name)
    Case PrintDivisions.EastSide
        getPrintDivision = Array("South East", "East East", 1, Sheet5.Name)
    Case PrintDivisions.WestSide
        getPrintDivision = Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet3.Name, Sheet3.Name)
    Case PrintDivisions.NorthAmerica
        getPrintDivision = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    End Select
End Function


Sub DivisionPrintOut()
    Sheets(getPrintDivision(NorthAmerica)).PrintOut Copies:=3

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Dim rng As Range, shtGroups As Worksheet

Set shtGroups = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Groups")

Set rng = shtGroups.Range(shtGroups.Range("B2"), _
                          shtGroups.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Application.Transpose(rng)).PrintOut
```